# How to extract slice from []interface{} in golang

Tags: go

My `[]interface{}` looks like this `[[1 2 3]]` when I print it. I want to extract `[1,2,3]` out of it as an array or slice so that I can make a search on it. 
Another solution is to search for an element like **1** in `[[1 2 3]]`, that will also work for me.

Comment: Can you sure some code you try before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexing on `[]interface{}` should work like `interfaceSlice[0]`

Example:

```
a := []interface{}{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
d := []interface{}{a}
var b []int
e := d[0].([]interface{})
for i := range e {
    b = append(b, e[i].(int))
}
fmt.Println(b)
```

Comment: it **does** work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
// if you know it is a first el in []interface{}
el := arr[0]
// and than you type cast it to []int
if arr, ok := el.([]int); ok {
    fmt.Println(arr[0])
}

// or if you want to do the same thing for all elements (searching...)
for _, el := range arr {
    if el, ok := el.([]int); ok {
        // use el as a []int here
        process(el)
    }
}
```

Comment: []interface{} don't support indexing, el := arr[0] won't work.

Comment: ok so in that case it is not []interface{} it is interface{}. In your place, I would first see what is the actual value inside interface, so do something like: fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(arr)).

Comment: @PrakharShukla in Go any type that starts with `[]` is a slice type, and slice types, *all of them*, support indexing, including the slice-of-empty-interfaces type, i.e. `[]interface{}`. So if `arr`'s *static* type is `[]interface{}` then `arr[0]` **will** work, period.

Comment: @PrakharShukla consider diving into the spec a bit, in this case reading the following section on slices may clarify some things. https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types. Also the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/7) is a great resource to go over the basics.